# What are the examples where parameter sharing make no sense in convolution network?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Where cant or shouldn't we use parameter sharing in a convolutional neural network?
I have read [here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) that :

> Note that sometimes the parameter sharing assumption may not make
>   sense. This is especially the case when the input images to a ConvNet
>   have some specific centered structure, where we should expect, for
>   example, that completely different features should be learned on one
>   side of the image than another. One practical example is when the
>   input are faces that have been centered in the image. You might expect
>   that different eye-specific or hair-specific features could (and
>   should) be learned in different spatial locations.In that case it is common to relax the parameter sharing scheme, and instead simply call the layer a Locally-Connected Layer.

So what exactly does this mean? 
Is it saying that we dont use parameter sharing at all in such cases ? or we just dont call it parameter sharing?! I'm lost here!
If its the first one, how come face images are any different than lets say, classifying different birds! or natural images ? 
And aside from that, what happens if the images are not centered? does it only account for centered images? why ?
And apart from faces example, what are other examples ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A convolutional neural network learns certain features in images that are useful for classifying the image. Sharing parameters gives the network the ability to look for a given feature everywhere in the image, rather than in just a certain area. This is extremely useful when the object of interest could be anywhere in the image.

Relaxing the parameter sharing allows the network to look for a given feature only in a specific area. For example, if your training data is of faces that are centered, you could end up with a network that looks for eyes, nose, and mouth in the center of the image, a curve towards the top, and shoulders towards the bottom.

It is uncommon to have training data where useful features will usually always be in the same area, so this is not seen often.